# How to send a mail when a plugin update found?

Tags: plugins

Is there any hook for when any plugin update is found to trigger a mail using PHP?
I found reference to upgrader_process_complete hook, but that is called after plugins are updated and not before.

Also, how can I fetch the list of plugins which have updates pending at a given time?

Comment: You're going to need to track which plugins you've sent emails for and which versions, otherwise you're going to recieve a lot of emails

Comment: @TomJNowell Right. That can be done by storing in database. But how do I fetch the plugins which has updates available?

Answer (score 1):

The relevant code is [wp_update_plugins()](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.4.1/wp-includes/update.php#L258). You can see that it stores its state in a site transient called 'update_plugins':

```
set_site_transient( 'update_plugins', $new_option );
```

and [we can hook that](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.4.1/wp-includes/option.php#L1820):

- pre_set_site_transient_update_plugins - called at the start of set_site_transient()
- set_site_transient_update_plugins - called at the end, if the value was changed

Note that

- `set_site_transient( 'update_plugins', ... )` is called twice as part of the update: once to update the last_checked timestamp, and once with the new-plugins-to-update list; the first call will always therefore have a changed value without necessarily having the list of updated plugins changed
- it can also be called when deleting plugins, to remove the update flag for any deleted plugin, but only once in this case.

I appreciate that hooking the site transient updates seems a bit of a hack, but there's no other obvious place to hook that the update check is complete. I have seen pay-for plugins hook these too as a way of generating update-needed for plugins hosted elsewhere.

---

Alternatively of course you don't need to hook the actual update, but you can instead schedule a cron job that checks `get_site_transient( 'update_plugins' )` (and `update_themes` and `update_core`) to generate the notification email.

Answer (score 0):

With the answer of Rup, you can create a simple mail with the wp_mail function.

It would look like this:

```
 wp_mail( get_bloginfo( 'admin_email' ), 'Subject title here', 'Text for mail here');
```

With `get_bloginfo( 'admin_email' )` you'll retrieve the admin's email you filled in during installation.